# Allow connection between two clients in VPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn

My setup: OpenVPN server (10.8.0.1), client1  (10.8.0.11), client2  (10.8.0.12)

My goal: Run a web server on client1 and allow client2 to reach it.

I have `client-to-client` and `topology subnet` uncommented in the server config, and set `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`. The clients succesfully connect to the VPN.

Searching for that yields a couple of different configurations mentioning pushing routes, but I wasn't able to find a comprehensive instruction.

I added `push route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0` to the server config, but that didn't help either.

Comment: What happens when you try to ping the clients from each other?  What do you see if you do a tcpdump on the tun interface on the server when attempting to ping between the two hosts?

Comment: ping works in both directions, `sudo tcpdump -i tun0` remains empty when pinging in either direction (but if I ping a wrong IP, then it shows sth. so it's the correct interface).

Comment: Have you configured iptables on server? Maybe it is dropping packets forwarded between clients or there is NAT that is modyfing these packets? Or try `dev tap` instead of `dev tun` - you will have "virtual ethernet".

Comment: I haven't configured iptables on the server. What do I need to configure there? I tried `dev tap`, but this also doesn't work. Then even ping doesn't work.